# How to efficiently use observe functions in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I am writing a web application in shiny and I am not to sure I am writing efficient code for conditional panels. What I want to happen is, if the user clicks "Yes" on the radioButton, then many more inputs will populate. I originally used "conditionalPanel" in my Ui followed buy 5 uiOutputs. However, I am noticing that the renderUi runs at the start of the app, even when the button does not say "Yes".  I have changed the code so I do not need a conditional panel BUT I am seeing the same thing occur. Is this efficient? I will have multiple uiOutputs, here is just one for example.

**UI.R**

```
radioButtons("add_indicator1", "Add long indicators", choices = c("No", "Yes")),
uiOutput("long1"),
```

**SERVER.R**

```
button1 = reactive({
input$add_indicator1 
})

output$long1 = renderUI({
if(button1() == "No"){NULL
}else{selectInput   ("indicator1", "Select the first long indicator", 
choices = c("Choices" = "", long_indicators))}
})
```

Comment: Without a fully-working minimal example, it's difficult to say for certain. However, I find the use of [`req`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/req.html) early in a reactive block to be very useful to prevent premature reactivity.

Comment: So req() inside reactive, and then how should I get it to the ui.R? Thanks

Comment: If you include `req()` inside the reactive or any render* function it will only continue executing the code when that requirement is met. Otherwise it will throw a silent error.

Comment: Not so much a silent error, it just skips the rest of the reactive block if the conditions aren't met. One difference, though, is that the UI *knows* that the output was skipped, so the interface remains consistent (vice a reactive block that returns `NULL`, such as using `if (...) {...}` without an `else`).

Comment: At least when you use `browser()` just before a `req()` and execute it, you will see that an error is printed in the console, if the condition is not met but that error doesnt appear when shiny is running. Therefore "silent error".